# window onclick listener not working properly

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, onclick

I have created a custom lightning web component that, if an specific div is found on the template and you're clicking outside of it, it must close the current div

```
constructor(){
    super();
    window.addEventListener('click', this.handleWindowClick.bind(this));
}
handleWindowClick = (event) => {
    if(this.template.querySelector('.mydiv')){
        if(this.template.querySelector('.mydiv').contains(event.target)) console.log('inside div');
        else console.log('outside div');
    }
}
```

And it's always giving me `outside div` even thought I'm clicking inside `.mydiv` element.

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?